# Is there a name for these types of functions?

Tags: c++

In C++ code that I've looked at, I've seen functions that go like this:

```
bool do_something(param_type & x)
{
   // do something with x
   // return whether the procedure was a success
   // ...
}
```

**Related example:**

```
size_t parse_int(std::string str, int & i)
{
    // set i equal to the integer parsed out of str
    // returns the number of characters parsed; return value will be 0 on error
    //
}
```

In other words, the function is performing some operation on a variable that is passed in, and is returning some info related to the operation. Is there a name for these types of functions? Is there somewhere that I can read more about them?

Comment: They are just simple functions with return values and some parameters.

Comment: ... that have side effects

Comment: yes, functions that take input arguments by reference and return a value.

Comment: I was wondering whether there's a fancy word for that style of writing functions

Comment: No, there is no special name for that type of operation

Comment: It's a very common practice, Holy Diver.  I think that learning more about C++ _in general_ will solve your curiosities about modifying parameter variables or returning a "status".  The function `main` itself returns "info related to the operation"

Comment: @HolyDiver Think that all functions either take input arguments or return a value or both so there's nothing special here.

Comment: @HolyDiver [Dio has to learn c++ in hell?!?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkysjcs5vFU&feature=kp) R.I.P. :-D

Comment: You might call them "output parameters". Or "confusing". It's usually better to return values using return values (returning a `struct` or `tuple` if you need to return multiple values). In the first case, consider using exceptions to report failure: unlike return values, they can't be ignored.